# Difference between linguistics and metamathematics

Tags: semantics, logic

Pardon my ignorance but I don't know a whole lot about linguistics. I actually wasn't aware this was a subject until I started investigating the foundations of mathematics and came upon metamathematics and semantics. Now to me it seems that metamathematics uses semantics to prove theorems in logic via set theory and interpretations/structures. I say "seems" because what logic books I have found seem to be a bit light on the semantic based theorems and only prove a couple formalized rules to produce "derivations/proofs", and the rest of the theorems of logic are derived from these derivations. It was a little disappointing for me because I found the semantic based theorems more interesting and decided to see if I could find any logic book that provided an introduction to semantics based techniques. This is what led me to linguistics. Apparantly semantics is apart of linguistics. So discovering this I looked to see if I could find what I was looking for in linguistics. Unfortunately for me this is such a vast subject that even within semantics there seems to be many goals and varieties that it has been hard for me to find what I'm looking for. So I was hoping someone here could point me in the right direction of linguistics to cover what I have just mentioned. I hope this question is not too broad or unrelated but any help will be greatly appreciated.

Update: ok I think my goal is to find a good intro to formal semantics, what is a good intro to formal semantics text?

Comment: I would say it is way too broad. Try to reduce the matter to one simple question of fact.

Comment: Some parts of linguistics use some of the same concepts and methods as some parts of mathematics.

Comment: There was already a question addressing your updated request. BTW, the books by Gamut are what I'd recommend.

Comment: It sounds like Montague Grammar would interest you.  There is some sort of text book, which I haven't seen.  Here is an online reference to Montague semantics: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/montague-semantics/

Comment: James McCawley's [book on language and logic](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/E/bo3618384.html) is a good read, with many good ideas and examples.